# Tailwindcss border not working after installing Flowbite

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, flowbite

My component is wrapped by this div:

```
    <div className="bg-gray-800 border border-gray-700 rounded-lg">

....
      </div>
```

After installing Flowbite the border wasn't taking any color.
[Look after install.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwRJF.png)

Somehow also the Dividers lost their color.

Comment: Tailwind is in the end just CSS. Does flowbite add some CSS to your page? If yes, then this will most likely overwrite your tailwind CSS. Change tailwind CSS so it has higher specifity than flowbite or remove flowbite CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add border-solid to className and it should work